# Dynamic input field using Form and actions in react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to using the new react router dom forms and actions. The normal forms that have static inputs are working fine? I want to know how can we make the input fields dynamic. Like for a specific field how to take multiple inputs for example I want to take interests from the user. Now the user can have multiple interests so he should have an option to add another interests field. basically, this is what I want to get from the user:

```
data={
  name:'name goes here',
  password:'password',
  interest:["interest one","interest two", "interest three"]
}
```

Now the main thing is want to do it using Form and Actions of react-router-dom and FormData ApI.
Here is my implementation till now:

```
import { Form } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

export const action = async ({ request }) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  console.log(formData);
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};

export default function Home() {
  const [interests, setInterests] = useState([{ val: "" }]);

  const handleFormChange = (event, index) => {
    let data = [...interests];
    data[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setInterests(data);
  };

  const addFields = () => {
    let object = {
      name: "",
      age: ""
    };

    setInterests([...interests, object]);
  };
  const removeFields = (index) => {
    let data = [...interests];
    data.splice(index, 1);
    setInterests(data);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Form method="post" className="form">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
        {interests.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="val"
              placeholder="interests"
              onChange={(event) => handleFormChange(event, index)}
              value={item.val}
            />

            <button onClick={() => removeFields(index)}>Remove</button>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button type="button" onClick={addFields}>
          Add More..
        </button>

        <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but when I console the data I only get the name, password, and one value of interest. Also if I add another field and start to write in that field it shows this warning:
`A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled.`
here is the code sandbox link also
`https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-chebyshev-yyznl3?file=/src/Home.jsx:0-1563`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each "interests" input a unique `name` attribute. Example, combine "interests" with the current array index.

```js
const handleFormChange = (event, index) => {
  setInterests((interests) =>
    interests.map((interest, i) =>
      i === index ? { val: event.target.value } : interest
    )
  );
};
```

```js
{interests.map((item, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <input
      type="text"
      name={`interests-${index}`}
      placeholder="interests"
      onChange={(event) => handleFormChange(event, index)}
      value={item.val}
    />

    <button onClick={() => removeFields(index)}>Remove</button>
  </div>
))}
```

If you would like to extract the interests back into an array you can map over the form data and search for the `"interests-*"` keys and reduce the values into an array.

```js
export const action = async ({ request }) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);

  const interests = Object.entries(data).reduce((interests, [key, value]) => {
    const [interestsKey] = key.split("-");
    if (interestsKey === "interests") {
      interests.push(value);
    }
    return interests;
  }, []);

  ...

  return data;
};
```

> Also if I add another field and start to write in that field it shows
> this warning: "A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be
> controlled."

This is because the `interests` state that is mapped is expecting array element objects with a `val` property, but the `addFields` function adds objects with only `name` and `age` properties. Add `val` as a defined property so new inputs have a defined `value` prop.

```js
const addFields = () => {
  setInterests((interests) => interests.concat({ val: "" }));
};
```

[image: Edit dynamic-input-field-using-form-and-actions-in-react-router-dom-v6]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, man you are a lifesaver. Do you recommend this kind of approach for building complex forms? or do you suggest something like react-hook-forms? Also can you use react-hook-forms with react-router-dom Form component????

Comment: @saimarshadd That's a bit subjective. For example, I don't personally see a strong case for the route loaders/actions when apps already have global state (*e.g. Redux, etc*) and handle network requests for data (*e.g. Thunks or Redux-Toolkit Query or GraghQL, etc*), using the loaders/actions don't mix well since they can't use React hooks that are pretty standard now. That said, loaders/actions do have a use case, for example, if you were using Server-Side-Rendering, the data could be fetched and served *with* the app page UI, like if you used Remix.run.